# edit message caption handler python telebot

Tags: python, api, telebot

`bot.edited_message_handler(func=lambda m: True)` не работает при изменении описания файлов, фото, видео т.д., только при изменении текстовых сообщений. Как я могу реализовать handler для получения события изменения caption в telebot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю такой хендлер впитает всё

```
from telebot import TeleBot, types

import config

bot = TeleBot(config.BOT_TOKEN)

CONTENT_TYPES = ["text", "audio", "document", "photo", "sticker", "video", "video_note", "voice", "location", "contact",
                 "new_chat_members", "left_chat_member", "new_chat_title", "new_chat_photo", "delete_chat_photo",
                 "group_chat_created", "supergroup_chat_created", "channel_chat_created", "migrate_to_chat_id",
                 "migrate_from_chat_id", "pinned_message"]


@bot.edited_message_handler(content_types=CONTENT_TYPES)
def handle_edit(message):
    print(message)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)
```